# How to give a PHP variables in this situation?

Tags: php, ajax, post

I want to make a php ajax post.(post value without refresh the page) here is my code. It can return the value and show in `<div id="msg"></div>`, But I also want to use this value, how to give a PHP variables in it? for example: `$name= <div id="msg"></div>` I tried to use `includ('value.php')` and combine two pages, put

```
<?php
echo $_POST["user_name"];
?>
```

in `<div id="msg"></div>`, they are all not correct method. How to do? and if there has other method can post post value in self page without refresh the page. pls teach me. thax.

index.php

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function saveUserInfo() 
{ 
var msg = document.getElementById("msg"); 
var f = document.user_info; 
var userName = f.user_name.value; 
var url = "value.php"; 
var postStr   = "user_name="+ userName; 
          var ajax = false; 
         if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
                 ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                 if (ajax.overrideMimeType) { 
                         ajax.overrideMimeType("text/xml"); 
                 } 
         } 
         else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
                 try { 
                         ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
                 } catch (e) { 
                         try { 
                                 ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
                         } catch (e) {} 
                 } 
         } 
         if (!ajax) { 
                 window.alert("wrong"); 
                 return false; 
         } 
ajax.open("POST", url, true); 
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
ajax.send(postStr); 
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() { 
   if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) { 
    msg.innerHTML = ajax.responseText; 
   } 
} 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body > 
<div id="msg"></div> 
<form name="user_info" id="user_info" method="post"> 
<input name="user_name" type="hidden" value="abc" /><br /> 
<input type="button" value="abc" onClick="saveUserInfo()"> 
</form> 
</body>
```

value.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST["user_name"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$name= "<div id='msg'></div>";` give that a try

Comment: $name= '<div id="msg"></div>'; // Or this, which is faster.

Comment: great, and I also want to know, which is faster?

Comment: It's single quote vs double quotes. PHP wouldn't look to inject variables on single quoted strings, which will make it a little faster. If it's a bottleneck in your script then your script is probably very tiny.